# Financial Products Markup Language

Tags: quants

I am asked to map financial products into XML. It can be in any format. I know there is an open specification FPML. Is that worth to adopt FPML rather than my own standards? Also, how common FPML is in the industry?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

we used fpml all the time in morgan. Of course its not surprising given their involvment in it.

Answer (score 7):

Quite common - such products as Calypso and Murex use their own derivations of FpML: CalypsoMl and MxML respectively.

Comment: I'd agree with quite common. In addition: I personally find that FpML and CalypsoML differ quite substantially in a number of design decisions, so I probably wouldn't call CalypsoML a "derivation" of FpML. I could imagine that mapping between the two can be quite a pain.

Answer (score 1):

Be prepared to extend any specification you will use.